# Date Formats in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In my recent pages on wordpress, the list items are seperated by date(MM/DD/YY) but on my new pages, the day(dd) are gone. What should I do to seperate my posts with MM/DD/YY. Thankss!

Answer (score 1):

Use the_time function in the template.

```
<?php the_time('m/d/Y'); ?>
```

Date format help:

```
F j, Y g:i a - November 6, 2010 12:50 am
F j, Y - November 6, 2010
F, Y - November, 2010
g:i a - 12:50 am
g:i:s a - 12:50:48 am
l, F jS, Y - Saturday, November 6th, 2010
M j, Y @ G:i - Nov 6, 2010 @ 0:50
Y/m/d \a\t g:i A - 2010/11/06 at 12:50 AM
Y/m/d \a\t g:ia - 2010/11/06 at 12:50am
Y/m/d g:i:s A - 2010/11/06 12:50:48 AM
Y/m/d - 2010/11/06
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the_time()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time) or [get_the_time()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time) functions and pass the arguments for the date format.

That's it.